# Get videos from youtube api from channel

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

How can i get videos from the youtube channel with duration and views count?

I tried this request:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet%2Cid&channelId=UC4H3KiOO86uiw2fAoZy6NRA&key=YOUR_API_KEY

but response doesn't contains duration/views count. Any ideas? Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That data is not available in the `snippet` field. Instead, make a second API call to the `channels.list()` with the video IDs and request the `contentDetails` and `statistics` fields in your response. You can find documentation on the [video resource here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource).